# set element's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, element

I'm creating an element in javascript, giving it an ID, and then accessing it via jQuery. I thought it would be simple enough but for some reason this is not working:

```
    var img  = document.createElement('img');
    img.id = "uploadedimg";
    if($('#uploadedimg').length==0)
            alert("it's not there");
        else 
            alert("it is there!");
```

The alert I get is "It's not there". I know how to create an element in jQuery but I want to know what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to append the element before looking for it in the DOM using jQuery.

Use the `appendChild` method to do that. For example:

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

And after that, access it with jQuery.

The other way would be to convert the element to a jQuery object directly, like this: `$(img)`. After that you can use jQuery's usual methods on it.

Comment: +1 Appending it to the DOM, or selecting it without looking for it in the DOM (`$(img)`) might be the correct thing to do, depending on desired effect.